# Two WordPress Installed Permalink Issues

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have installed two WordPress platforms (one on example.com and another on example.com/sub).

Both have different themes.

example.com is an e-commerce website and example.com/sub is a blog.

I have set my WordPress Address (URL) to example.com/sub for the second WordPress installation and example.com for the Site Address (URL).

My current URL structure is example.com/sample-post.

When I visit one of my pages (e.g. example.com/blog-post), it sends me to a 404 error page with the example.com theme.

What needs to be done to fix this error?

Comment: the home and siteurl both include the http(s):// prefix.

.htaccess 


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /information-advice/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /information-advice/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

*information-advice ( subfolder where the second wordpres is installed)

Answer (score 0):

Root domain
WordPress Address (URL) : http://petssys.com
Site Address (URL)  : http://petssys.com

Sub directory 
WordPress Address (URL)  http://petssys.com/information-advice
Site Address (URL)   http://petssys.com

Just to make you aware I do have 2  .htaccess files, one for each WordPress install

subdirectory .htaccess file

```html
> 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /information-advice/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /information-advice/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

root domain htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/cache-manifest
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vcard
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-cross-domain-policy
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/schema+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.geo+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How do i get to the browser network log?